# Spawning random platforms in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So in my quest to make a game like the very popular zigzag game, I am stuck at randomly generating platforms. The platforms generate randomly in X,-X,Z,-Z directions. I have written my code where it generates the platforms. I might have taken a very long approach (alternative approaches if any)

```
                void Start () 
                {
                    lastPos = platform.transform.position;
                    size = platform.transform.localScale.x;

                    InvokeRepeating("SpawnXZ",1f,0.2f);
                }

                void SpawnX()
                {   
                    Vector3 pos = lastPos;
                    pos.x += size;
                    lastPos = pos;
                    Instantiate(platform, pos, Quaternion.identity);    
                }

                void SpawnZ()
                {
                    Vector3 pos = lastPos;
                    pos.z += size;
                    lastPos = pos;
                    Instantiate(platform, pos, Quaternion.identity); 
                }

                void SpawnNegX()
                {
                    Vector3 pos = lastPos;
                    pos.x -= size;
                    lastPos = pos;
                    Instantiate(platform, pos, Quaternion.identity);  
                }

                void SpawnNegZ()
                {
                    Vector3 pos = lastPos;
                    pos.z -= size;
                    lastPos = pos;
                    Instantiate(platform, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                }

                void SpawnXZ()
                {

                        int rand = Random.Range(0, 6);
                        if (rand < 3)
                        {
                                SpawnX();
                        }
                        else if(rand >= 3)
                        {
                                SpawnZ();
                        }

                        if(--counter == 0) { CancelInvoke("SpawnXZ"); };


                    if(counter == 0)
                    {   
                        counter = 25;
                        int r = Random.Range(0,2);
                        if(r == 0)
                        {   
                            InvokeRepeating("SpawnNegXZ",0f,0.2f);
                        }
                        else
                        {       
                            InvokeRepeating("SpawnXNegZ",0f,0.2f);
                        }
                    }

                }

                void SpawnNegXZ()
                {
                    int rand = Random.Range(0, 6);
                        if (rand < 3)
                        {   
                                SpawnNegX();
                        }
                        else if(rand >= 3)
                        {   
                                SpawnZ();
                        }

                    if(--counter == 0) { CancelInvoke("SpawnNegXZ"); };


                    if(counter == 0)
                    {   
                        counter = 25;
                        int r = Random.Range(0,2);
                        if(r == 0)
                        {   
                            InvokeRepeating("SpawnXZ",0f,0.2f);
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            InvokeRepeating("SpawnNegXNegZ",0f,0.2f);
                        }
                    }
                }

                void SpawnXNegZ()
                {
                        int rand = Random.Range(0, 6);
                        if (rand < 3)
                        {   
                                SpawnX();
                        }
                        else if(rand >= 3)
                        {   
                                SpawnNegZ();
                        }       


                    if(--counter == 0) { CancelInvoke("SpawnXNegZ"); };


                    if(counter == 0)
                    {   
                        counter = 25;
                        int r = Random.Range(0,2);
                        if(r == 0)
                        {   
                            InvokeRepeating("SpawnXZ",0f,0.2f);
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            InvokeRepeating("SpawnNegXNegZ",0f,0.2f);
                        }
                    }
                }

                void SpawnNegXNegZ()
                {

                        int rand = Random.Range(0, 6);
                        if (rand < 3)
                        {
                                SpawnNegX();    
                        }
                        else if(rand >= 3)
                        {   
                                SpawnNegZ();
                        }

                    if(--counter == 0) { CancelInvoke("SpawnNegXNegZ"); };


                    if(counter == 0)
                    {   
                        counter = 25;
                        int r = Random.Range(0,2);
                        if(r == 0)
                        {   
                            InvokeRepeating("SpawnNegXZ",0f,0.2f);
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            InvokeRepeating("SpawnXNegZ",0f,0.2f);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I have clubbed xz, -xz , x -z and -x -z. I call platform spawning in X and Z direction first, then switching to -XZ or x -Z and so on. But there are 2 main issues.

[image]

PS : those small black squares are nothing but diamonds (ignore them).

They either form a 2X2 block or overlap each other.

How do I avoid these? or is there a simpler way of generating platforms that I am missing.

Comment: What is not OK about the sections you have circled?

Comment: Am i correct to state that a platform may never touch more than 2 other platforms (previous and next). If so, then you could store the platforms in a list and on placing a new one, check if the next target position isnt occupied and does not connect to an additional platform

Comment: @lockstock what is not okay that the platforms spawn in 2x2 pattern which will then cause issues with the player movement.. the new platforms should not be adjacent to already spawned platforms and also not overlap them

Comment: @immorality yes they should not touch.. I'll try that approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an array to indicate which tiles are occupied:

```
bool[,] tiles = new bool[N,N];
```

or a dictionary

```
Dictionary<XZ, bool> tiles = new Dictionary<XZ, bool>();
public struct XZ { public int X; public int Z; }
```

whenever a tile is spawned check the value to see if it is possible to spawn or not:

```
           void SpawnXZ()
           {
                int x = (int) (lastpos.x / size);
                int z = (int) (lastpos.z / size);

                int rand = Random.Range(0, 6);
                if (rand < 3 && !tiles[x + 1, z])
                {
                    SpawnX();
                    tiles[x + 1, z] = true;
                }
                else if(rand >= 3 && && !tiles[x, z + 1])
                {
                    SpawnZ();
                    tiles[x, z + 1] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                     ...
                }
```

Note that this code will not work, and it's just a starting point for you to develop it further.

Comment: Thanks @bijan.. I'll try that and let you know 

Comment: is there a way I can achieve this using raycast? I know I can but I'm just not able to figure it out.

Comment: @UdaykiranBitla yes that would be easy, you need to cast from (pos.X + size/2 , -10, pos.z + size/2) in direction of (0,1,0) with a distance more than 10

Comment: It may be from (pos.X,-10,pos.z) depending on your object

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll give it a try tonight. Will keep you posted.Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to solve it using Raycast. :) Cheers and Happy Coding!!!